# Как отправить запрос авторизации на сервер используя java

Tags: java

Как отправить запрос авторизации на сервер используя java.  Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки Apache HttpComponents (Apache HTTPClient), Jersy, Selenium, даже фраемворк Spring :3 .

Воспользовался кодом @SeniorPomidor -а

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("В ведите логин: ");
    String login = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.print("В ведите пароль: ");
    String password = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(password);

    System.out.print(getRest("http://n7701-sys253:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa", login, password));
}

public static String getBase64(String USERNAME, String PASSWORD){
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD).getBytes());
}

public static String getRest(String request, String login, String password) {
    String res = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(request);

        String encoding = getBase64(login, password);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "utf-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            res += line + "\n";
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
  }  
}
```

Заменил строку

```
System.out.print(getRest("http://n7701-sys253:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa", login, password));
```

на

```
System.out.print(getRest("http://n7701-sys253:8080/rest/api/2/issue/", login, password));
```

Результат ошибка 405 :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://n7701-sys253:8080/rest/api/2/issue/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at zapr_and_atswer.Program.getRest(Program.java:45)
    at zapr_and_atswer.Program.main(Program.java:27)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
        Подставляю свою задачу (реиндекс) :

```
   System.out.print(getRest("http://n7701-sys253:8080/rest/api/2/reindex?type=FOREGROUND&indexComments=true&indexChangeHistory=true&indexWorklogs=true", login, password));
```

Получаю результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы дать адекватный ответ, нужно понимать какой тип авторизации поддерживает сервер

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а он не стандартизированный ???   Можно  на примере какого либо простого сайта увидеть простейший запрос. Просто я думал что по протоколу HTTP/1.1  один и тот же вид этого  запроста (для стандартных сайтов)

Comment: *отправить запрос авторизации на сервер используя java* - basic, jwt, oauth, сертификат и т.д. что именно?

Comment: @GVArt любой пример который может понять человек.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String getBase64(){
       return Base64
               .getEncoder()
               .encodeToString(
                       (USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
                       .getBytes()
               );
    }

public static String getRest(String request) {
    String res = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(request);

        String encoding = getBase64();

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            res += line + "\n";
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Данный метод использует для аутентификации username и пароль, возвращает в виде строки то, что вернет вам сервер

Comment: увы выводит стандартно весь сайт   в xml, и тот факт что я авторизацию не прошёл,   <input type="hidden" title="ajaxCommsError" value="Невозможно связаться с сервером JIRA. Это может быть временный сбой или сервер недоступен. ">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxServerError" value="Сервер JIRA доступен, но вернул сообщение об ошибке. Мы не уверены в результате этой операции.">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxErrorCloseDialog" value="Закройте это диалоговое окно и нажмите обновление в браузере">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxErrorDialogHeading" value="Разрыв связи">

Comment: я этот метод проверил на джире. пришлите ваш урл после основного домена

Comment: System.out.print(getRest("http: / / n7701-sys253:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa ", login, password)); (без пробелов пробелы я добавил что бы он текст как гипер сылку не видел )

Comment: `/rest/api/2/issue/` что говорит?

Comment: вот, обновил весь вопрос. Спасибо что поддерживаете.

Comment: @timob256 потому что надо использовать `http://n7701-sys253:8080/rest/api/2/issue/`. `http:/ /n7701-sys253:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa`  вернет вам html-страницу.

Comment: вот, обновил весь вопрос.

Comment: вы понимаете, что сервер вам говорит? окей. берите таску, у которой у вас есть доступ, например, называется JRA-9. и выполните 
 `http://n7701-sys253:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9`

Comment: вы вообще прочли, что я вам сказал??? внимательно еще раз читаете! *берите таску, у которой у вас есть доступ, например, называется JRA-9*. у вас есть таска с названием JRA-9 ? конечно нету! подставьте туда вашу задачу

Comment: Подставил (поставленную) задачу, но почему-то стандартная ошибка.

Comment: прекратите обновлять вопрос! у меня `/rest/api/2/reindex?type=FOREGROUND` возвращает 200.  а у вас проблема на вашей стороне.  вы хотели пример - пример есть!

Comment: Непонятки ;_; он мне пишет   `Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://n7701-sys253:8080/rest/api/2/reindex?type=FOREGROUND`